# Chamadas de procedure PL/SQL

Tags: sql, pl-sql

Estudando PL/SQL me deparei com o seguinte código:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE incluir_segmercado(p_id IN NUMBER , 
                                    p_descricao IN VARCHAR2)

IS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO segmercado
        values(p_id, UPPER(p_descricao));
    COMMIT;
END;

EXECUTE incluir_segmercado(3, 'Farmaceutico')

BEGIN 
    incluir_segmercado(4, 'Industrial');
END;
```

O autor utilizou 2 maneiras de fazer a chamada da procedure criada acima, porém, não explicou a diferença de chamar por EXECUTE e chamar por BEGIN, existe algum tipo de diferença entre chamadas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EXECUTE` (ou exec, na sua forma mais abreviada) executa apenas uma `procedure`

`BEGIN/END` pode executar mais de um comando ao mesmo tempo.

Bons estudos!

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda!